# How to pass extra information to search results page using hook node_api

Tags: search, nodes

I want to show some extra information on the search result page in Drupal. I want to implement it in a module (and not in the theme).

I am using this code in my custom module:

```
function custommodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op){
     case 'search result':
      return 'TEST';
      break;
    }
```

When I debug the statement, the line return 'Test' is executed.
I would expect this extra information to show up at: search-result.tpl.php in the variable $info.

However this extra information is not included. Has anyone got a clue how to pass this extra information so it shows up at the result page?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<?php

function your_custom_module_name_preprocess_search_results(&$variables){
    $var['info'] = 'the_value_you_want_to_include';
}
?>
```

Now you can use the variable $info in search-result.tpl.php.

Comment: That was not exactly what I was looking for I guess. I have to implement this in the template.php (which is part of a theme). I am looking for a solution to alter the display of the search results by using a module. I have a multi site solution. Each site uses the same theme, but the display of the search results can vary. Each site can have is own module to configure stuff. So that's why I am looking for a module solution instead of a theme solution.